# Change/Remove "Return-Path" header in Apache James

Tags: apache-http-server

After a mail has been processed by Apache James it seems that the "Return-Path" header is set. I want to change its value - or if that is not possible - prevent it from being generated altogether. I tried using the [RemoveMimeHeader mailet](https://james.apache.org/mailet/standard/mailet-report.html#RemoveMimeHeader) in the mailetcontainer.xml, but that does not seem to work. Configuration looks as follows:

```
<mailet match="All" class="RemoveMimeHeader">
<name>Return-Path</name>
</mailet>
```

I added this mailet before and after the RemoteDelivery mailet in processor state outbound, but both do not seem to be working. In context the whole outbound processor looks as follows:

```
            <processor state="outbound" enableJmx="true">

                          <mailet match="All" class="RemoveMimeHeader">
                            <name>Return-Path</name>
                    </mailet>


                    <mailet match="All" class="RemoteDelivery">
                            <outgoingQueue>outgoing</outgoingQueue>

                            <!-- Delivery Schedule based upon RFC 2821, 4.5.4.1 -->
                            <!-- 5 day retry period, with 4 attempts in the first hour, two more within the first 6 hours, and then every 6 hours for the rest of the period. -->
                            <delayTime>5 minutes</delayTime>
                            <delayTime>10 minutes</delayTime>
                            <delayTime>45 minutes</delayTime>
                            <delayTime>2 hours</delayTime>
                            <delayTime>3 hours</delayTime>
                            <delayTime>6 hours</delayTime>
                            <maxRetries>25</maxRetries>

                            <!-- The max reties which will used if no A or MX record for the domain was found. -->
                            <!-- If 0 it will fail on first time -->
                            <maxDnsProblemRetries>0</maxDnsProblemRetries>

                            <!-- The number of threads that should be trying to deliver outgoing messages -->
                            <deliveryThreads>10</deliveryThreads>

                            <!-- If false the message will not be sent to given server if any recipients fail -->
                            <sendpartial>true</sendpartial>

                            <!-- By default we send bounces to the "bounce" processor -->
                            <!-- By removing this configuration James will fallback to hardcoded bounce -->
                            <!-- notifications -->
                            <bounceProcessor>bounces</bounceProcessor>

                            <!--
                            CHANGE ME: Replace smtp relay hostname  -->
                            <heloName>[host]</heloName>

                    </mailet>


        </processor>
```

Any help of how the value could be changed (statically for now) or removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this inside a custom Mailet. Only take care, that "Return Path" is not an ordinary header: It is automatically set by James for an outgoing mail using the value of envelope sender - a value that can only be set for an SMTP message.